# block incoming call in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, block

I am developing an app which blocks incoming calls. Currently, when an incoming call arrives on the device, it is blocked. But after returning from the blocked call, the screen turns to the dial call screen, and shows a dialog to alert that you have a missed call.

I want to block the incoming call, then when hung up, the screen is the home screen. How do I make this happen?

---

My second question: what is the permission in blocking incoming call? How do I add it to my app? I added "ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_IDLE_TIMER" but it's not useful.

**Edit1:**

this is my code in my application.

```
private void blockincomingcall(){
    int master_volume= net.rim.device.api.system.Alert.getVolume(); //net.rim.device.api.notification.NotificationsManag er.getMasterNotificationVolume();
    System.out.println("Master Volume "+master_volume);
    net.rim.device.api.system.Alert.setVolume(0);
    int alert_volume = Alert.getVolume();
    Main.log("Master Volume after setting "+alert_volume);
    int notifi_volume = NotificationsManager.getMasterNotificationVolume();
    Main.log("Master Volume 1 after setting "+notifi_volume);
    EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent ev1 = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, ((char) Keypad.KEY_END), KeypadListener.STATUS_ALT, 100);
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    EventInjector.invokeEvent(ev1); 
    EventInjector.invokeEvent(ev1); 
    net.rim.device.api.system.Alert.setVolume(master_volume);
   //System.out.println("Master volume 2 "+master_volume);
    requestBackground();
}
```

when, it runs on os5.0 it can block calls. but the screen will turn to the dial screen,and show a notify dialog that a new incoming call. and the volume set is no effect. it runs ok on os 7.0 and 6.0 but no effect on volume set. what should i do ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thats a good piece of malware, but anyway:

1. Detect incoming call
2. Terminate it.
3. Put your app on foreground again.

For #1 You need to detect active calls (use `PhoneListener` class). #2 is the most difficult step and you are going to need key injection to accomplish it. It is a bit hackish:

```
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent ev = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, ((char)Keypad.KEY_END), KeypadListener.STATUS_ALT);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(ev);
```

The #3 point can be done in two different ways:

- 3.1: Pass a reference to your app to the `PhoneListener` implementation and then call `<YourUiApplication>.requestForeground()`
- 3.2: Given that code in `PhoneListener` **runs inside the phone app** (this should answer your second question), call:

  UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();